# Generic type of flatten nested value objects

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design, transformation

I'm trying to define generic types for domain/aggregate and entities that would enable me to build aggregates that include a number of domains. All in all this would lead to nested value object classes.

In order to simplify API response I would like to provide a toObject() function that would return a somewhat flatten object with strings (or better yet; ValueType).

In the example below I would like order.toObject() to return the type and object as specified in the end.

I would also like to be able to define a recursive/deep generic type for BaseDomain.toObject()

Any ideas? I welcome feedback and thoughts

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w16P8N)

```
//// What I would like to solve /////

// Define a generic type that flatten a object by removing all class specific and only keeping the properties
type FlattenProperties<T> = any;

// My poor attempt
/*
type FlattenProperties<T> = T extends IBaseEntity<infer U> ? U
    : T extends IBaseList<infer U>
        ? T['items'] extends IBaseDomain<infer Z>[] ? [...T['items']]: FlattenRecursiveEntityProperties<Z>  //Not sure of how to recurse iterate a array 
        : U[]
    : T extends object ? {[K in keyof T]: FlattenRecursiveEntityProperties<T[K]>}
    : T;

*/

//// Helpers //////

interface IValue<ValueType> {
    value: ValueType
}

interface IBaseEntity<ValueType> {
    value: ValueType
}

abstract class BaseEntity<ValueType> implements IBaseEntity<ValueType> {
    readonly properties: IValue<ValueType>;
    constructor(value?: ValueType) {
        this.properties = { value: value ?? {} as ValueType };
    }
    get value(): ValueType {
        return this.properties.value;
    }

}

class ObjectId extends BaseEntity<string> {
    constructor(id?: string) {
        super()
        this.properties.value = id ?? 'GeneratedID';
    }
}

interface IBaseList<ItemType> {
    items: ItemType[]
}
abstract class BaseList<ItemType> {
    readonly items: ItemType[];
    constructor(items?: ItemType[]) {
        this.items = items ?? [];
    }
    getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
    add(item: ItemType) {
        this.items.push(item);
    }
}

interface IBaseDomain<Interface> {
    readonly properties: Interface;
    readonly _id: ObjectId;
    toObject(): FlattenProperties<Interface>
}

abstract class BaseDomain<Interface> implements IBaseDomain<Interface> {
    readonly properties: Interface;
    readonly _id: ObjectId;
    constructor(object?: Interface, id?: ObjectId) {
        this._id = id ?? new ObjectId('#a-generated-value#');
        this.properties = object ?? {} as Interface;
    }
    get id() {
        return this._id
    }
    toObject(): FlattenProperties<Interface> {
        return {} as FlattenProperties<Interface>;
    }

}



///// Definition of domains ///////

interface IProduct {
    name: string;
    description: string
}

class Product extends BaseDomain<IProduct> {
    constructor(name: string, description: string) {
        super({ name: name, description: description })
    }
}

interface IOrderLine {
    product: Product;
    qty: number;
}

class OrderLine extends BaseDomain<IOrderLine> {
    constructor(product: Product, qty: number) {
        super({ product: product, qty: qty })
    }
}

class OrderLines extends BaseList<OrderLine> { }

interface IOrder {
    orderComment: string;
    orderLines: OrderLines
}

class Order extends BaseDomain<IOrder> {

}

///// Example run /////

const toyTruck = new Product('Toy truck', 'Yellow plastic toy truck');
const toyDuck = new Product('Duck', 'Made famous by Duck Sauce');

export const order = new Order({
    orderComment: 'Some new shiny toys',
    orderLines: new OrderLines([new OrderLine(toyTruck, 1), new OrderLine(toyDuck, 100)])
});

const htmlResponse: Expected = order.toObject(); // Type = Expected
htmlResponse.orderLines[0].product.name; // Type = string

type Expected = {
    orderComment: string,
    orderLines: {
        product: {
            name: string,
            description: string
        },
        qty: number
    }[]
}

type Expected2 = {
    orderComment: string,
    orderLines: {
        product: IProduct,
        qty: number
    }[]
}

declare var x: Expected;
declare var x: Expected2;
//declare var x: FlattenProperties<IOrder>; //TODO: Make valid
```

Comment: You didn't include the `Enitity`  class. Wouldn't `interface IDom<props> {
    toObject(): props
}` work ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Wyb5dw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvV8RW) would meet your needs but I'd like to see your example cleaned up first (`Enitity` vs `Entity`, the missing `Entity` class, class property initialization, `string` vs `boolean` for `arg2` maybe) before I post an answer.  Let me know though if missing something about what you want.

Comment: Yes, I omitted those, they was just shells. 

toObject(): props would include the value object as object and I'm trying to flatten it so Dom1.data.arg1 = Dom1.data.arg1.value . If I use props straight out then Dom1.data.arg1 = Entity1

Comment: @jcalz you were spot on. I hate myself right now :)
Please post it and I'll mark it as answer

Comment: Would something like this suit your need ? https://tsplay.dev/W48peW the `FlattenEntityProperties` type

Comment: @PerLinde are you trying to transform `Dom1` or `IDom1Props`?  Do you really want `IDom1Props` to reference `Dom2` instead of `IDom2Props`? If `Dom2` has more properties in it than are mentioned in `IDom2Props` do you want the output type to have those properties or not (like [this](//tsplay.dev/Nab0Pm))? Without a well-formatted example with concrete use cases it's hard to tell.  Could you please [edit] the example in your question to resolve these questions?  I could post an answer but I'm worried that you'll realize there's a problem with it once you check it against other use cases.

Comment: @jcalz I have tried to update the code to better describe a use-case. I'm trying to keep the domain interface, eg. IProduct as specific for the domain as possible, meaning only the properties that is unique for that domain at the same time there will be cases I need to refer to another domain instance, eg. OrderLine.product: Product (the interface would not be enough I think?)

Comment: When I look at that code I see at three errors that seem to be unrelated to your question.  Could you resolve those?  I don't understand the "Type = Flatten Order" comment; I think a specific input/output type relationship would be more useful, where you show exactly some input types and exactly what you expect them to be as output.  Have you tried [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nab0Pm) with your use cases?

Comment: @jcalz this become a long question. Sorry about that. I have updated the code once more and implemented toObject() so that it returns what I expect. I'm still not able to define the generic type for toObject() I'm stuck in the array part, ie. be able to iterate the array and set the recursive type

Comment: First: I think [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/WKVqzm) might work for you. If so I can write up an answer. If not, what's missing?
---
Second: Your example code has errors unrelated to your problem.  I'm asking you (again ) to please resolve them so that they do not distract attention from your actual issue.  The point of a [mre] is to make the issue as clear as possible.  After you have received the answer you want, this question and answer will stay on SO to be a resource for future readers, so it's helpful to fix unrelated problems even if neither of us is actually confused by them.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for your quite enormous patience. This worked as a charm. I adjusted it a bit to be more strict to string, after all this is what I need in terms of http response. See. https://tsplay.dev/mL4qam

Please post your answer and I'll mark it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks `FlattenProperties<T>` should be a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types), where the base cases are if `T` is a primitive type or if `T extends IBaseEntity<U>` for some `U`.  If `T extends IBaseDomain<U>` or `IBaseList<U>` for some `U` then you can recurse into `U`.  Or if `T` is an object type, you can [map its properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) recursively.  Something like this:

```
type FlattenProperties<T> =
    T extends IBaseEntity<infer U> ? U :
    T extends IBaseDomain<infer U> ? FlattenProperties<U> :
    T extends IBaseList<infer U> ? FlattenProperties<U>[] :
    T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: FlattenProperties<T[K]> } : T;
```

You mentioned in comments that you might want the primitive or `IBaseEntity` leaf nodes to be `string` instead of some other type, so in that case it would look like:

```
type FlattenProperties<T> =
    T extends IBaseEntity<infer U> ? string :
    T extends IBaseDomain<infer U> ? FlattenProperties<U> :
    T extends IBaseList<infer U> ? FlattenProperties<U>[] :
    T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: FlattenProperties<T[K]> } : string;
```

But for now I'm going to use the first definition since it's more general.  Let's see if it works:

```
type FPOrder = FlattenProperties<Order>
/* type FPOrder = {
    orderComment: string;
    orderLines: {
        product: {
            name: string;
            description: string;
        };
        qty: number;
    }[];
} */
```

That's the type you expected, so it looks good!

---

Just to be painfully clear about what's happening, let's partially evaluate `FlattenProperties<Order>` "by hand":

```
FlattenProperties<Order>
```

becomes

```
Order extends IBaseEntity<infer U> ? U :
Order extends IBaseDomain<infer U> ? FlattenProperties<U> :
Order extends IBaseList<infer U> ? FlattenProperties<U>[] :
Order extends object ? { [K in keyof Order]: FlattenProperties<Order[K]> } : T;
```

Since `Order` is not an `IBaseEntity` we go to the second line.  `Order` is an `IBaseDomain<IOrder>`, so `U` is inferred as `IOrder` and the type becomes

```
FlattenProperties<IOrder>
```

Now we have

```
IOrder extends IBaseEntity<infer U> ? U :
IOrder extends IBaseDomain<infer U> ? FlattenProperties<U> :
IOrder extends IBaseList<infer U> ? FlattenProperties<U>[] :
IOrder extends object ? { [K in keyof IOrder]: FlattenProperties<IOrder[K]> } : T;
```

`IOrder` is neither an `IBaseEntity`, nor an `IBaseDomain`, nor an `IBaseList`.  It is an `object`, so we now have

```
{ [K in keyof IOrder]: FlattenProperties<IOrder[K]> }
```

which becomes

```
{
    orderComment: FlattenProperties<string>;
    orderLines: FlattenProperties<OrderLines>
}
```

Well `FlattenProperties<string>` is just `string` because `string` is a primitive that does not extend any of your `IBase*` types.  And `FlattenProperties<OrderLines>` becomes  `FlattenProperties<OrderLine>[]` because `OrderLines extends IBaseList<OrderLine>`.  So now we have

```
{
    orderComment: string;
    orderLines: FlattenProperties<OrderLine>[]
}
```

We could keep going, but hopefully you can see how this will eventually evaluate to the desired type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQ4AgdQCwQwFzASTAdwPYFcA2ATMWBLAawFMw40wBnNLANzNBAChmQwAREgMwIDsyMMAHMSAgE4EAxuQCeABzJxYCblnhwxYIWgBGAKxJSEu2WHEkAtmjr9h2rFjBT1VKtUVSCvGTD540PiwzUhJ5O3IoMnlxNEVxOAISKlY4BTIAMXU4TT4ABVj4xOSAHgAVAD4wAF5mMHqwMrASAA9cnHdEACEYKhIAUT5EtJL+bhJxMABVKoB+ajhJPnsALjqGptb2zp6+jjRLGH5RvnHJmbB5rI0xAriJ4qoSi7WGxua2sQ6kXZIAGQIVDgJzO0zmYGuOVuhQeSSeMwA2gBdMCvDYfbZgPSGYyXMAAbzACIA0mB+GBSLI0Nx3r1GiSUVsvu4Mhg+MYCIE8QIGJMVmBiUj+ZDcncinDygyqgBfVGNADcrCYYAAEiQsPF3EwWMx+JpxNwYFIyIgAGowLAYEglc2WkhldJVfHrep0C1W-m2q0OxTMaWsPUTQ3Gn69AZDAgjL32x0El1gN12z3umO+-3MGC6IHiI0IFy9dy-QbDWQ2lM+khVAiWeRYKxiOA7MPFyOl6MVp3xiwwHCBYJgGL3BJw-lmlNlu0dxVvKSBbMYYxocQACkTVtmycn6QAlHG3m9lICAHSD8XJGoEhMp-lrsizeb42V09vpMDS6cNf1vUQIW-L7ebt6r7OvuDQWHAGDiHwkTHqesLJEet4fvU6bpvmbhgAA8gYRhwIgeBMv4hbNhGIzZnYnYznOiwLhQK4EDgG4LEswi7iBoHUBg8T-vGB5QLBMLDght4XgxlzzAA5AA4mIEzwCQOCIBwEnIW+foBkMQZGiavwAkCJSIJolgdnuDSRlYVCjkZFbIupmbZrmziuMRfR6cChlWCZ7H1N2vZBGY5mWJZSDWekyKqbOfDzou9FGVQTEecZYVImxvENIeVBHoF7jVGScXiUSSKqV+DQ-olVD-qZoHgZB0EZVlcXFfGPY4MugVWZ5O5Vfu9XZSeGBUFAbVGduTXpoGBraaGewHEcfAGZpk3GpRYEkD2fZmHBQnBYgi3BiQqm+RtYAAPoMfy2E4nhOCqRQl24f+wrZKKgmPAt+r7RU6kZlmiyOehLkkPshzHLtH3aVWNZ1pYDZNjNIPzWDWnLd1R3+QOr0jkge3aYda1+f2Z04BdOHGPhEXUeItFLsu2K4QlOPGgANGSjEk1d+GpRxMGZUTol4PeYACCgWGk9dy4SQAxDAAC0ogSPJOAy7eksSaNaX1PVW2PBedO4oLj7aJ0jMHfGJX1D+rOVd5+41VBPNHkTZvxndYuPRCz3QkOb1I0tlbdW8dvQYbdIil7Z5PL7n1Nd9SrKlwvB8JGnLQdSYC9gjWrasAGngyGiB3DgtHdXwMAw-y5HLKpODJFIkjyIkgQV4sdjfQDYCF8XhHfL8wNzQZnfGCt9SRdFdHLqX5fMXYLM11QdcEA3KfNyxXMcVQXETMuhKTyQ-K77Ptf143fD8nPC9L1y0rbs740m0gmHiDX4gAgI3WDkXxj8oPcCqQAjmkfeGBLC6AmIqNCzksJPwmK-Mg3dAZ91Bo-Z+sDh7OEptTFcH9aLf1iJ-OALMAGyCASAiYa9QIb24oSbBX8MZoHwYQwBYAiFvhvm8f0ECCxQJQfwc88CwC6UBMCZBMDeFOjUrqe+iARGTBtkuZ+ABhA4MMhgrzsKpeRoiBDBRkbAlInCMIyIxMyARYZEGIxkZ2b62owD9BaGXWsZAqbQW1KwUeCAKCyDKFTKQRALzCw7ng2iEsyhoDMDRXxEkWYSQAJrqiwGgEWtZeiJBkJ48gPiiBq0VO48gYSOALj8blAJP8JYFMidEgAsj2MghprADTAKYTghSwAAGUYALhINk1grR5BLjzNRLE0DJjFJICLGR294yaPEEoywKi4D8gkq0g4ZAAmDX4OEsJVAolTOGXo-eYzuFaOSMuBEATdG8OXJ47xhSWYAEZtws3OXsy5njylEHuQABk+duFKfp1bMDSIoCEeQjG5TDvkTGpRLFsAAFRyGBRkUFwyLxyOGbM+Zaiq67J4do-kNs3g0IWQHDiu8sXCFUtzc+x9l7T2xdzd8GtmFML4MA0B4hirhT9GAWFOdmC5KgHASwWAABKyQ+lRTILlaZR5XZXX-PKMA7AKwXjsZ4TQOBmCCuFWKqgEq+hHmmXohEnykQniCcYI8u9FXKtfLlSuwhUivjVbhBSqKcUTAxQ2clTMPUv14cFAlDQiX4qZW8MldLhC+u5m8ali8T7kqZdKaNHEiEkPZWbWy6YgVkBdcYBSAAmd1bxpletUZGlN9QjUBtDdzENSAf6Vv3GmoWbKJiZqRN9Gu+YLBXkmC0fkeaNWKm7eoXtbp+2DpaOqwtI6jBjrIBOsAA6PY3Ehd7CU0jhkVEVMwIAA)

Comment: Thank you for a good a detailed answer. I’m quite impressed 